# WebSphere Authentication in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, websphere

I am trying to pre-authenticate users to WebSphere in an ASP.NET application. The situation is that I want to display content from WebSphere in an ASP.NET web part...and it only works if the user already has the WebSphere authentication cookie.

In my research, I found lots of information about bolt-on products for WebSphere that would allow various Single Sign-On (SSO) options, but I am working a point solution and cannot be adding things or changing the configuration of WebSphere.

Is there a way for me to check for the cookie's presence and then send an HTTP request in code, or call some native WebSphere web service, that will perform the authentication and give the user the cookie they need to access the WebSphere content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also fighting a similar issue. I think, the key will be to catch the LPTA and LPTA2 tokens. I am searching for relevant topics on how to do this. You may also dig into it.